# How can i auto change the rotation angle of google street view?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm using google street view , i want to make users look around the street when they enter my site.

I have tried this:

```
var lookAround = function(){
pano.getPov().heading = pano.getPov().heading + 50;
if(pano.getPov().heading < 100){
    setTimeout("lookAround()",2000);
}
};
```

but it doesn't work , the rotation parameter have actually changed , but the view of the picture doesn't.

Can any one help me with this ?many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make any changes to the panorama you have to make it visible by using the method setVisible. In your case you have to call pano.setVisible(true) after you set the new heading.